# React Native app doesn't have network connection when enable remote js debugging

Tags: android, react-native, remote-debugging

I almost spent whole day to search everywhere, tried to figure out this but no luck.

I used my cell phone samsung S10 installed android10 for android app dev under React Native. Usually I just connect my cell phone to my pc via USB, cd into my project, run 'react-native run android', wait for the metro bundler start up and loading, then app was installed in my cell phone, most of the time I enable 'remote JS debugging' and code based on the chrome console log, everything was smooth.

However suddenly one day after enabling 'remote JS debugging' as usuall, the app kept tell that 'no internet connection', and from the chrome console, every requests were all timed out. I didn't do any modification/configuration (at least I can't recall any) either in my phone or my pc dev environment, and the data server worked good as well at that time. When disable 'remote JS debugging', the app then could connect internet without any issue, worked back to normal.

I have two RN app projects, one is RN 0.55 and the other is RN 0.62, this happens on both so it is not related with RN or projects themselves.

I tried in different PC with the same cell phone, issue both happened, so it's not realted with PC dev environment.

I tried another cell phone then everything works correctly so it is obviousely something wrong in my samsung S10, although I didn't change anything but I still went through all the config especially in developer options, USB debuggin is on, USB configuration is 'Transferring files/Android Auto' as usual, nothing looks fishy or wrong. Also tried to turn off and on developer options to reset them, tried to clean chrome cache, but no, didn't fix.

To summarize: the app in my S10 cell phone can't connect to network when it is operated in 'remote JS debugging', can anybody help me out or give some hint here? btw I don't want to reset my S10. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you share the details of what you're getting, and summarize cause this question is really long, with no necessary details.

Comment: Hi @OscarDavid, sorry I know this question looks ugly but I tried to clarify every steps during the process. could you be more specific what kind of details you need at this time? thanks!